# How to apply a css class to certain table column and row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function which applies a blinking animation css to each of a table cell's border. I am trying to apply the blinking effect only to the 2nd column and if possible the 2nd row so it gives the effect that there is an error on the 2nd row of the 2nd column. here is a JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/eah5f8wp/

my html:

```
<body>
  <table id = "tableContainer">
    <tr>
      <th class="heading">aaa</th>
      <th class="heading">bbb</th>
      <th class="heading">ccc</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="column">aaa</td>
      <td class="monitor">bbb</td>
      <td class="monitor">ccc</td>
    <button id="alarm" type="button">Start Alarm</button>
  </table>
```

javascript: I have tried using:

```
$("#tableContainer th:nth-child(" + 1 + "), #tableContainer td:nth-child(" + 1 + ")").addClass("blink");
```

but it doesnt work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#alarm").click(function(){
                $("#tableContainer").addClass("blink");
    });
});
```

css:

```
.heading 
{
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #C1C1C1;
}

.monitor 
{
  text-align:center;

}

.row 
{
  text-align:right;
  background-color:rgb(210, 251, 255);
}

div 
{
  align-content:center;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td 
{
  min-width: 80px;
  width: auto;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);z
}

tr:nth-child(even)
{
  background-color: white;
}

/* blink effect */
.blink th, .blink td {
    animation: blink 200ms infinite alternate;
}

/*blink effect color switcher*/
@keyframes blink {
    from { border-color: white; }
    to { border-color: red; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As with a previous answer, I changed `.blink th, .blink td` to `.blink`.

I added variables containing the desired row and column to blink, and changed the selectors as follows:

```
$('#tableContainer tr:nth-child(' + highlightedRow + '), #tableContainer tr td:nth-child(' + highlightedColumn + '), #tableContainer tr th:nth-child(' + highlightedColumn + ')')
```

Here's the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eah5f8wp/3/

Oh yeah, and I changed the blinking to be the background colour of the cell as the borders only partially flashed and it was making my eye twitch. Update: And it doesn't work properly with `border-color`. Hmm.

Comment: This works and ought to have been accepted as the answer (upvote)

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet, change:

```
.blink th, .blink td {
```

to:

```
.blink {
```

Or change it to:

```
th.blink td.blink {
```

Your current CSS selector applies the animation to th and td elements that are descendants of `.blink` elements, which is why in your fiddle demo all of the cells started blinking when you added `.blink` to the table itself. But in the following line of JS that targeted individual cells, you added the `.blink` class directly to the th and td elements, which didn't match your stylesheet's selector:

```
$("#tableContainer th:nth-child(" + 1 + "), #tableContainer td:nth-child(" + 1 + ")")
    .addClass("blink");
```

Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eah5f8wp/2/